# Trouble getting .aspx page using php curl

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I'm trying to login to a secure aspx site using curl, and retrieve some of the account's data.
The page uses the aspx __VIEWSTATE to keep track of the browser's state.  From checking the request headers here is the sequence:

user GETS from Login.aspx (including __VIEWSTATE)
user POSTS __VIEWSTATE, loginName and loginPassword to login.aspx -> server responds with 302
user GETS Submissions.aspx

submissions.aspx is a table of different clients referred to by __EVENTTARGET=dgrdSubmissions$ctl0x$ctl00 where the first $ctl0x represents that client's row.

user POSTS _*VIEWSTATE,*_EVENTTARGET and an AdvisorView param to submissions.aspx -> server responds with 302
user GETS Policy.aspx

This works fine in the browser (Chrome - The site suspiciously breaks in Firefox with Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown) but in my php script the GET Policy.aspx responds with the login page and not the expected client info.

Here is my code (minus error-checking and page displaying):
Helper Functions:

```
function curl_page($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

function curl_ssl_page($url="",$postdata=""){
$ch = curl_init();
$cookie = 'cookie.txt';
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

return $result;
}

function curl_get_page($url=""){

$ch = curl_init();
$cookie = 'cookie.txt';
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
return $result;
}
```

Pages

```
Pages - Login:

if(isset($_POST['user-name'])) {
    //GET login page
    $url = "http://www.gryphinonline.ca/Login.aspx";
    $login_page = $this->curl_page($url);

    // get viewstate
    $regexViewstate = '/__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';
    $regexEventVal  = '/__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';

$viewstate = $this->regexExtract($login_page,$regexViewstate,1);
$eventval = $this->regexExtract($login_page, $regexEventVal,1);

//Post to login page
$postdata = '__VIEWSTATE='.rawurlencode($viewstate)
     .'&txtLoginName='.$_POST['user-name']
     .'&txtPassword='.$_POST['password']
     .'&Start=Login+%2F+Ouverture+de+session';

$this->curl_ssl_page($url,$postdata);
header("Location:http://url-edited/submissions");
}

Pages - Submissions:
    $url = "http://www.gryphinonline.ca/Submissions.aspx";
$submissions = $this->curl_get_page($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($submissions);

// scrape for data including viewstate
$view = $dom->getElementById('dgrdSubmissions'); 
if(!$view) header("Location://url-edited/login");

    $h_data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$h_data = $h_data->item(0);

if(isset($_POST['__EVENTTARGET'])){
    $postdata=array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $postdata[]=$key.'='.$value;
    }
    $postdata = implode('&', $postdata);

    $this->curl_ssl_page($url,$postdata);
    header("Location:http://url-edited/policy");        
}

Pages - Policy:
    $url = "http://www.gryphinonline.ca/Policy.aspx";
$policy = $this->curl_get_page($url);
```

All the HTTP requests and cookies are identical as far as I can tell.  Anyone have any idea what is going on here?  Is this possibly related to the site's problems with Firefox or am I misunderstanding something basic?

I've been at this for a few days and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had forgotten to urlencode the POST string to submissions.